# About Finite Elements Method and stabilization using Upwind Scheme

Tags: galerkin-methods

I'm asking here cause I have a doubt about approximate solution of this problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}-\epsilon u''+bu'=0 \\ u(0) = 0, u(1)=1 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

which is a diffusion transport problem. I found the approximate solution using FEM in Matlab, and I tested for $\epsilon = 10^{-1}$ and $\epsilon = 10^{-3}$. In the second case I have the convection term $b$ dominating over diffusion term $\epsilon$. So I'm using an Upwind stabilization scheme by substituiting $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon_h = \epsilon(1+\psi(Pe))$ where $\psi(t) = t$ and $Pe$ is Pèclet number ($\frac{bh}{2\epsilon}$).

My question is, should I substitute $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon_h$ just in my approximation I find using FEM, so basically when I assemble the final matrix ($A= \epsilon_h*K + b*H$) or even in the original problem? (I mean when I find the exact solution at the beginning that I will compare to approximate solution, do I have to consider $\epsilon$ or $\epsilon_h$?).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You only have to substitute in the matrix assembly because if you do the substitution in the original problem then it doesn't remain the diffusion transport problem.